# SSIS script task to collect lineage IDs

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I have an SSIS script task that collects extended error information.

The contents of the script are as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
/// or parent of this class.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]

public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    Dictionary<string, string> lineageIds = null;

    public void Main()
    {
        // Grab the executables so we have to something to iterate over, and initialize our lineageIDs list
        // Why the executables?  Well, SSIS won't let us store a reference to the Package itself...
        Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Value = ((Package)Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Parent).Executables;
        Dts.Variables["User::lineageIds"].Value = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        lineageIds = (Dictionary<string, string>)Dts.Variables["User::lineageIds"].Value;
        Executables execs = (Executables)Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Value;

        ReadExecutables(execs);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    private void ReadExecutables(Executables executables)
    {
        foreach (Executable pkgExecutable in executables)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(pkgExecutable.GetType(), typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost)))
            {
                TaskHost pkgExecTaskHost = (TaskHost)pkgExecutable;
                if (pkgExecTaskHost.CreationName.StartsWith("SSIS.Pipeline"))
                {
                    ProcessDataFlowTask(pkgExecTaskHost);
                }
            }
            else if (object.ReferenceEquals(pkgExecutable.GetType(), typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ForEachLoop)))
            {
                // Recurse into FELCs
                ReadExecutables(((ForEachLoop)pkgExecutable).Executables);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessDataFlowTask(TaskHost currentDataFlowTask)
    {
        MainPipe currentDataFlow = (MainPipe)currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject;
        foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 currentComponent in currentDataFlow.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
        {
            // Get the inputs in the component.
            foreach (IDTSInput100 currentInput in currentComponent.InputCollection)
                foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 currentInputColumn in currentInput.InputColumnCollection)
                    lineageIds.Add(currentDataFlowTask.ID.ToString() + currentInputColumn.ID, currentInputColumn.Name);

            // Get the outputs in the component.
            foreach (IDTSOutput100 currentOutput in currentComponent.OutputCollection)
                foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 currentoutputColumn in currentOutput.OutputColumnCollection)
                    lineageIds.Add(currentDataFlowTask.ID.ToString() + currentoutputColumn.ID, currentoutputColumn.Name);
        }
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
}
```

This used to work correctly on SQL Server 2014.  However since upgrading to SQL server 2017 the task gives the following error message on the line:

```
MainPipe currentDataFlow = (MainPipe)currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject;
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ST_47767930511349f4b94ba74c27240570 but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D3931AC-822D-414C-8F10-7447A54BA55C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Has anybody else seen this since upgrading to SQL Server 2017?

Comment: We got lots of errors when moving from lower SQL to higher ones.  Have you tried opening the package, opening the script task, rebuilding it, and closing it again?  (sometimes just needs to recompile), that fixed a lot of our errors when upgrading

Comment: We have tons of problems upgrading scripts between versions of SQL *and* VS. So many that we started removing them from our packages.

Comment: @Brad all the packages have been opened and closed.

Comment: and each script tasks themselves have been open and closed?  Just opening the package wont do it, you need to open each individual script task.

Comment: Just to be safe, open the script task, build it, close it and save the package.

Comment: @Brad We haven't needed to do that so far.  We have a lot of script tasks that have been regression tested after the upgrade and this is one of the few issues we've found.  Found the solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the Com object returned by currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject was coming from a newer version of Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.

To fix the issue I removed the reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap and replaced with version 14 of the same assembly.

Then I altered the following line:

```
MainPipe currentDataFlow = (MainPipe)currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject;
```

to

```
IDTSPipeline130 currentDataFlow = (IDTSPipeline130)currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject;
```

Comment: C# scripts in SSIS are...as graceful as a walrus. But have an upvote!